# Simple jQuery conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple script on my site.

If header is visible it'll remove the class `fixed`, if not, it'll add it.

```
$(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $(".wrapper > header").visible(true) ?
                $(".wrapper > main > nav").removeClass("fixed") :
                $(".wrapper > main > nav").addClass("fixed");
        });
    });
```

As well as toggling between the `fixed` class, I'd also like to toggle between a `fixed2` class.

So add:

```
$(".scrollWrapper").removeClass("fixed2") :
$(".scrollWrapper").addClass("fixed2");
```

But I'm unsure how to add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you would have two statements, you need to revert to a normal if/else:

```
if($(".wrapper > header").visible(true)){
     $(".wrapper > main > nav").removeClass("fixed");
     $(".scrollWrapper").removeClass("fixed2");
}else{
     $(".wrapper > main > nav").addClass("fixed");
     $(".scrollWrapper").addClass("fixed2");
}
```

Alternatively, don't use any conditionals and use the `toggleClass` method for this:

```
var toggle = $(".wrapper > header").visible(true);
$(".wrapper > main > nav").toggleClass("fixed", toggle);
$(".scrollWrapper").toggleClass("fixed2", toggle);
```

NOTE: the above supposes you have a `visible`-plugin, as otherwise that method won't work. To test for visibility you should use is `.is(':visible')`

Answer (score 0):

There is no property called visible in jquery object. So you need to use

```
$(".wrapper > header").is(":visible)
```

so the expression becomes :

```
 $(".wrapper > header").is(":visible") ?
            $(".wrapper > main > nav").addClass("fixed") :  $(".wrapper > main > nav").removeClass("fixed") ;
```

For Toggling :

```
$(".scrollWrapper").toggleClass('fixed fixed2');
```

Comment: He was trying to add `fixed2` to `.scrollWrapper`, not the nav block.

Comment: @Honesty: Yes copy-paste error. Fixed it now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

if your doing a few things based on a condition its probably better to use an *if* statement as opposed to ternary.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(".wrapper > header").visible(true)){
            $(".wrapper > main > nav").removeClass("fixed");
            $(".scrollWrapper").removeClass("fixed2");
        }else{
            $(".wrapper > main > nav").addClass("fixed");
            $(".scrollWrapper").addClass("fixed2");
        }
    });
});
```

Ternarys are great but as everything they have their use-cases. This may not be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if-else statement instead of a ternary one. After all, jQuery is a JavaScript library.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(".wrapper > header").visible(true)) {
            $(".wrapper > main > nav").removeClass("fixed");
            $(".scrollWrapper").removeClass("fixed2");
        } else {
            $(".wrapper > main > nav").addClass("fixed");
            $(".scrollWrapper").addClass("fixed2");
        }
    });
});
```

If you're really set on using only ternary statements, you just have to add another one:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(".wrapper > header").visible(true) ?
            $(".wrapper > main > nav").removeClass("fixed") :
            $(".wrapper > main > nav").addClass("fixed");
        $(".wrapper > header").visible(true) ?
            $(".scrollWrapper").removeClass("fixed2") :
            $(".scrollWrapper").addClass("fixed2");
    });
});
```